# How to give a hybrid proof that IND CPA secure implies multiple query IND CPA secure and vice versa?

Tags: encryption, chosen-plaintext-attack

For a public-key encryption scheme (Gen,Enc,Dec), the textbook definition of IND-CPA security is the following:

1. The challenger runs (pk,sk)←Gen and sends pk to the adversary.
2. The adversary performs some computation, chooses (m0​,m1​) and sends them to the challenger.
3. The challenger runs ct←$Enc(pk,mb​) , b←${0,1}, and sends ct to the adversary.
4. The adversary performs some computation and outputs a bit b′.

For a secret-key encryption scheme (G,E,D), the definition must allow multiple encryptions. A usual version is:

1. The challenger runs k←$G , b←${0,1}.
2. The adversary can adaptively present many challenges (mi0​,mi1​) and get back E(k,mib​).
3. The adversary outputs a bit b′.

Can we provide a hybrid argument to prove that an adversary that wins the second game with say, Q queries, can also win the first game? How would that argument be structured?

Comment: The first game is about public-key encryption and the second one is about symmetric-key encryption. It sounds like you are asking whether a public-key encryption is also a symmetric-key encryption?